# custom initWithNibName not showing up in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, initialization, cocoapods, nib

So I tried to make some changes to a pod someone wrote only they did it in `objective c` So instead of rewriting the entire thing to `swift` I figured I would just make the changes in `objective c` since it would take less time then completely rewriting it.

However I can't seem to get one of my customisations working.

I needed to override the `initWithNibName` to add an additional parameter to the initialiser. Here is what it looks like now

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil dayNib:(NSString *)nibDayNibOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        _allowClearDate = NO;
        _allowSelectionOfSelectedDate = NO;
        _clearAsToday = NO;
        _daysInFuture = NO;
        _daysInHistory = NO;
        _historyFutureBasedOnInternal = NO;
        _autoCloseCancelDelay = 1.0;
        _dateTimeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        _slideAnimationDuration = .5;
        _selectedDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _selectedDateViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _allowMultiDaySelection = NO;



        if(nibDayNibOrNil == nil) {
            [self setDayNibName:@"MHDateDay"];
        } else {
            [self setDayNibName:nibDayNibOrNil];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

However when I install the pod and try to initialise the view controller in a swift project it will give me the following suggestion

```
var dp = MHDatePickerViewController(nibName: <String>, bundle: <Bundle>)
```

so for some reason it doesn't seem to see the customisation I did to the `initialiser`

Does anyone happen to know where I went wrong? why it isn't showing me the correct options?

Comment: Did you update the *.h file as well?

Comment: @DanielT. goddamn you are right completely forgot to do that...